# What official adventure awards the "Home Sweet Home" story award?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league, product-identification

A while ago (last spring) I played a 5e AL adventure and received a story award, I believe it was called 'home sweet home', in which each adventurer recieved a home in the city the adventure took place in - but I don't remember what the name of the city or adventure was.

Does anyone know, or know how to find out?

Comment: Do you have a slip of paper or something to represent this award? Usually AL DMs hand those out so that you can verify (at least to a bare minimum of plausibility) that you got it at an official event and you're not just making it up. If you have the slip, it might have a clue you've overlooked.

Comment: @SirTechSpec Certs have fallen out of favor. And that was before the virus sent everyone on line.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the adventure that would help us place the season? (If it were Mulmaster I'd know to look at season 2, for instance.) Were there lots of demons, or giants, or excursions to undermountain...?

Comment: looks like it all got answered, ty

Comment: @EvokerofMulmaster If you've got follow-up questions about the award, please [ask them in a new question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) rather than extending the scope of this one into whole new quesiton territory. I've rolled back your reivsion to your post. You can access the text of the previous version in your edit history, accessed by visiting the [edited X time ago](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/170446/revisions) link at the bottom center of your post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module in question is [CCC-BMG-18 ELMW1-3 *The Battle of Elmwood*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/204922/CCCBMG18-ELM-13-The-Battle-of-Elmwood), the third part of the Misaligned Trilogy by Baldman Games.

> Characters that successfully completed this adventure earn the story reward “Home Sweet Home”. [...]
>
> This character has been given a plot of land in Elmwood by the Elmwood Council to use as their permanent residence. This plot of land can be either sized for a comfortably large house in the main area of the town of Elmwood OR about an acre of bare land out in the farmlands for some crops or a ranch, a barn, and a farmhouse. Future Elmwood adventures will have more information about how to upgrade this residence.

The module includes a player handout depicting the deed/title.

[image: The grateful town of Elmwood]

A module in the subsequent series, [CCC-BMG-34 ELM 2-1 *Tendrils in the Fog*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/254008/CCCBMG34-ELM-21-Tendrils-in-the-Fog), offers a small benefit (a free potion) to characters who have "Home Sweet Home", but no information about upgrading the residence is included in the ELM2 trilogy. There is no third series I'm aware of.

Comment: thank you, is it AL legal to make up some designs, etc, buy some finishings?  Maybe say it is where I spend my downtime?

Comment: also, do you have a pdf of the 'deed'? @l.j.l.

Comment: @EvokerofMulmaster Strangely, there are DDAL legal resources that cover the cost of ships but I don't think I've ever seen the price of a house. I can't imagine a DM having a problem saying your character has a house there - after all, everybody has a home *somewhere*. As for the deed, it's part of the PDF of the module. I'll try to see if I can extract it cleanly - no promises, though.