# What are the mechanics governing the Home Sweet Home award?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

A while ago (last spring) I played a 5e AL adventure and received a story award named 'Home Sweet Home' form the DDAL module 'Battle of Elmwood'.

As [quoted by T.J.L.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/170489/22138),

> Characters that successfully completed this adventure earn the story reward “Home Sweet Home”.  [...]
>
> This character has been given a plot of land in Elmwood by the Elmwood Council to use as their permanent residence. This plot of land can be either sized for a comfortably large house in the main area of the town of Elmwood OR about an acre of bare land out in the farmlands for some crops or a ranch, a barn, and a farmhouse. Future Elmwood adventures will have more information about how to upgrade this residence.

What rules govern it?  IE, what does it cost to actually build a house?  can I add a forge?  does it already have a house?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one of the Elmwood Authors here.

We're working on a third trilogy as well as an introductory adventure to the region. I don't currently have a timetable on such, but there's more Elmwood adventures forthcoming.

As far as mechanics, the Home Sweet Home award is transitioning toward being a Legacy Event, as seen in the Eberron Oracle of War campaign. Don't expect much on the mechanics side as Story Awards and Legacy Events are moving away from those. Instead, think of things like different paths in future adventures or opportunities to do things that non-residents wouldn't be able to partake in.

As stated for now, it has many of the same story award or certified player housing options do - you're welcome to develop it as you see fit, provided that you aren't getting mechanical gain out of it. Ie, using it as a "I train in my forge and use downtimes days to train in proficiency with smithing tools (if that's still a thing)" or "if we're in Elmwood or nearby, we can hang out at my house there" are fine but saying "I work at my forge, give me more gp" is not. Caveat - this is how I understand the rules, but YMMV with any given DM and of course, AL campaign staff are welcome to correct me.

Comment: We *love* hearing from primary sources around here! Thanks for coming by and helping add some knowledge to the world =)

Comment: exactly what nitsua said!  Nothing like the author to answer my question.  Welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Story rewards are a DDAL-specific thing. I'm reluctant to use the word "mechanic" because of how loosely or incompletely written many of them are. While some of them do grant a mechanical benefit - e.g., there's one that gives access to a Unicorn ally for three adventures, there's an Epic that grants advantage vs. disease, et. al. - many of them are *just* story elements. They won't affect adventures in any way, and therefore don't have any mechanics.

As mentioned in [my answer to your previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/170489/22138), no "information about how to upgrade this residence" was forthcoming in the subsequent trilogy. If Baldman Games publishes a third Elmwood trilogy, there might be, but as of the time of writing, there are no additional mechanics. That's the entire text of the story reward.